# Update multiple tables with a single query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In my database there are 85 tables and around 62 tables have a common column `ArchiveID`. I have other table `EDSArchiveHistory`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EDSArchiveHistory]
(
    [ArchiveID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ArchiveDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL
)
```

When I insert any records into `EDSArchiveHistor`, I want to take the `ArchiveID` of the inserted record and update all tables that have an `ArchiveID` column.

Basically I write query to find all tables that have `ArchiveID` column

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM SYS.TABLES 
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID AS NAME
                    FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
                    WHERE NAME LIKE '%ARCHIVEID%') 
  AND NAME <> 'EDSARCHIVEHISTORY'
ORDER BY NAME
```

but I don't know how to update those tables with a single query.

Please help me if it possible.

Comment: You can do it through trigger or stored procedure.

Comment: You need to write a stored procedure that loops over every table in a record/cursor and then execute a dynamic statement to update that table with a given archieid (probably where archiveid is null).

Comment: yes i will go through trigger but i don't what query to write to update all tables inside trigger. if i write multiple update query so i have to write 60+ update query. i think this is not good approach.

Comment: @ConsiderMe  archiveId is null

Comment: @Anjyr Dynamic SQL is what You need. You have table containing tablenames. Then use cursor or while sentecies ( your taste ) scannig your table with names. For each line create Sql expression as nvarchar and exec sp_executesql.

Comment: A single `UPDATE` statement can only ever update a *single table* - no way around that. So if you need to update 60 tables, you'll have 60 `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: I think this is a one time update. right?

Comment: yes @DimaSUN i am talking about Dynamic Sql Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating multiple table through single query is possible through SQL Dynamic Query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_ArchiveManagment 
@paramARCHIVEID INT
AS
DECLARE @TempTableList TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),NAME NVARCHAR(300))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTableList (NAME) (
        SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES 
        WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (
                        SELECT OBJECT_ID AS NAME FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
                        WHERE NAME LIKE '%ARCHIVEID%' 
                        ) AND 
            NAME <> 'EDSARCHIVEHISTORY')

    DECLARE @REC_ID AS INT
    SET @REC_ID = 1
    DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    WHILE (@REC_ID <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTableList))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TblName VARCHAR (200)      
        SET @TblName=(SELECT NAME FROM @TempTableList WHERE ID=@REC_ID)
        SET @SQLQUERY= 'UPDATE '+@TblName+' SET ARCHIVEID ='+CAST(@paramARCHIVEID AS VARCHAR(4))+' WHERE ARCHIVEID IS NULL'
        EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
        SET @REC_ID= @REC_ID + 1
    END
END
```

[Here is good article for Dynamic SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this isn't technically a single query because it creates a dynamic SQL statement that contains many queries.  Nonetheless it's a relatively simple way to update all of the tables.

```
DECLARE @archiveId int

-- After inserting into EDSArchiveHistory
SET @archiveId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql += 'UPDATE ' + NAME + ' SET ARCHIVEID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @archiveId) + ';'
FROM SYS.TABLES 
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID AS NAME
                    FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
                    WHERE NAME LIKE '%ARCHIVEID%') 
  AND NAME <> 'EDSARCHIVEHISTORY'
ORDER BY NAME
EXEC(@sql)
```